# How to add custom features in my drupal website?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

I have downloaded a theme and installed in my drupal website. All the static contents are already created but I would like to add some custom features to the website.

Should I create custom module(s) and installed into my website or are there anyway to add those features, thanks.

Comment: features means what features? It depends on the functionality you want to build. If the features are provided by any contributed module then you can install them and enhance your website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually I would like to add some event management features but the modules I found on the community do not really meet all my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the features are not provided by a contributed module and you can't fullfill your requirements by Site-Buildung you should create a custom module. On http://drupal.org is an introduction [Developing Drupal Modules](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try on it.

Answer (score 0):

For "smaller", theme related features you don't even have to create your module - you can place your code in template.php file in your theme directory.